# Channels supported by Firebase A/B testing

Tags: firebase, firebase-ab-testing

I am trying to understand about Firebase A/B testing. I don't get one thing basically. Does Firebase A/B testing support for Web, Mobile and Single page React like app as well? I see Firebase documentation, but it doesn't say about it. Then, reading about Firebase A/B testing by changing Remote config file. but never get whether it supports for Web, and Single page apps like Angular, React etc. as well? If yes, are they released SDKs/Library for Mobile, Web and single page apps to integrate with our apps and test. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase A/B Testing (via Remote Config) only supports experimentation on mobile right now.